# What is is the best method to iterate loop on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, loops

For example, I have 200 records in a table . My requirement is I need to fetch those 200 records and generate csv files. Then, it will be send to a specified ftp folder.This is just an exmaple, but in general what is the best way to follow:

**Method one:** Fetch all the ids in array and get the array count and iterate a for loop and call the function.

```
$ids_array = array which stores all the id from the related table.
$array_cnt = count($ids_array);
for($i=0;$i<$array_cnt;$i++)
{
    generateCsv($ids_array[$i]);
}
```

Here the generateCsv function will call 200 times and generate 200 csvs

**Second Method:** Fetch all the ids from the table with comma separated and pass to the function like below

```
function generateCsv($ids) 
{
    $qry = "SELECT soem fields from the table where ids IN ('".$ids."')";
    // SOME CSV generation code will comes here.
}
```

So in the above two methods which one is the best one ?

Comment: Do you need to fetch the ids separately? Can you not just do a JOIN in the  original SELECT to get all the details? But your first method seems to suggest you do a separate SELECT for every single id, which will be quite slow. Your second method relies on the number of ids being small enough for an IN clause to cope with it (not a major issue with MySQL, but can be a problem with other flavours of SQL)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to loop at all. Mysql has an excellent functionality built into generate CSV. It's called [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

> SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE writes the selected rows to a file. Column and
>   line terminators can be specified to produce a specific output format.

Once you have generated the file. Consider using SFTP or some other secure protocol to transfer the files rather than using FTP which sends passowrds in clear text.

Comment: ok, here generate csv is just an example. But in general way i have some update operations etc... In general scenario what is the best one?

Comment: I have answered the question you have asked. And this answer is correct Your comment is far too broad. Please post a specific follow up question.

Comment: Appreciate if you could mark this answer as correct since it adequately and correctly answered the original question you posted. Thanks